# Flask app running with Flask but not Gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import, gunicorn

I created a Flask app for some of my projects. There is a main app.py in the `~/flasksvr` directory, and the folder structure looks a bit like this:

```
flasksvr/
> __init__.py (empty)
> app.py (main app)
> modules/ (subprojects)
> > __init__.py (empty)
> > subproj1.py
> > subproj2.py
> > subproj3.py
```

When I run app.py, it imports all the subprojects with URL prefixes like this:

```py
from .modules.subproj1 import app as sp1app
from .modules.subproj2 import app as sp2app
from .modules.subproj3 import app as sp3app

app.register_blueprint(sp1app, url_prefix='/sp1')
app.register_blueprint(sp2app, url_prefix='/sp2')
app.register_blueprint(sp3app, url_prefix='/sp3')
```

Anyways, running it with `flask run -h 0.0.0.0 --debug` works great, but when I run it with `gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0`, it gives me the error

```py
from .modules.subproj1 import app as sp1app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I tried changing the `from .modules.subproj1 import app as sp1app` part to `from modules.subproj1 import app as sp1app`, and it worked. But *in* my subproject 1, I am importing a SocketIO app with `from ..app import sock` (where `sock` is `sock = SocketIO(app, ping_interval=10)` in app.py). Then *that* gives me the error `ImportError: Attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Why is this happening? Why does it work with regular Flask but not gunicorn? Using Python 3.9 on Debian 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With folder structure

```
 flasksvr/
> __init__.py
> app.py         <----- path is here
> modules/
> > __init__.py  
> > subproj1.py  <----- in this file subproj1.py is `from app import sock` because your root path now at app.py
> > subproj2.py
> > subproj3.py
```

When you run project in gunicorn, Gunicorn will load all resource to worker and the root path is at app.py `gunicorn app:app`.It's different from running the flask run default, when call it will import

If you want to run both flask run and gunicorn. You can use:

```
flasksvr/
> app.py        <------ from modules.subproj1 import app as sp1app
> modules/
> > subproj1.py <------ from app import sock
> > subproj2.py
> > subproj3.py
```

Comment: Here is sample a flask tree with run both gunicorn and flask run https://github.com/tanthienqn/sample-flask-structure

Comment: But now when I try to run it with `flask run`, it gives the error
```from modules.subproj1    import app as   sp1app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```
I want to be able to run it with gunicorn for just regular running, and flask for testing

Comment: never mind, I figured it out. I just added a bunch of `try: ... except: ...` statements each time anything was imported relatively and it works now